# About definition of lexicographical order

Tags: definition, order-theory

**Def.** let be $\preceq_A$ a total order, $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n),(b_1,b_2,...,b_n) \in A^n$, $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \leq^d (b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ if one and only one of the following holds is true: $$a_1 \prec_A b_1$$$$a_1=b_1 \wedge a_2 \prec_A b_2$$$$a_1=b_1 \wedge a_2=b_2 \wedge a_3 \prec_A b_3$$$$.$$$$.$$$$.$$$$a_1=b_1 \wedge a_2=b_2 \wedge ... \wedge a_{n-1}=b_{n-1} \wedge a_n \prec_A b_n$$with $a_i \prec_A b_i  \equiv a_i \preceq_A b_i \wedge a_i \neq b_i$

Is it correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: That seems right to me, but I don't think two of these can be true at the same time, so 'one and only one' can be simplified to 'one' or 'at least one'.

Comment: That is a plausible definiton. What exactly are you asking for?
Note that $\le^d$ should be associated with $\preceq_A$ and needs a little more clarification. Your definition taken for $<^d$ and defining $A \le^d B :\Leftrightarrow A=B \vee A<^d B$ seems like the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reflect that $\le$ is associated with $\preceq$ and $<$ with $\prec$ you could use
$$\begin{align*}a\prec b & :\Leftrightarrow a\preceq b \wedge a\neq b\\
A<^d B & :\Leftrightarrow \exists k: a_i = b_i \forall i<k \quad \wedge \quad a_k \prec b_k\\
A\le^d B&:\Leftrightarrow A<^d B \vee A=B\end{align*}$$

If you want to only define $\le^d$ but equivalent to the above (i.e. eliminate usage of $\prec, <$), write this:

$$A\le^d B:\Leftrightarrow A = B \vee (\exists k: a_i=b_i \forall i <k\quad \wedge\quad a_k \ne b_k \wedge a_k \preceq b_k)$$
$k$ could be called the "common prefix length" or something.

Comment: great.. thanks soo much! :)

Comment: @AnatolyIvanovichMaltsev Happy to help :)

Comment: in this case $\leq^d$ is total order in $A^n$, is correct?

Comment: @AnatolyIvanovichMaltsev Yes, it indeed is. You can verify all axioms for exercise if you wish; it revolves around proving that the $k$ from the definition always exists and using that $\preceq$ is a total order on the alphabet.